# Condense IF statement with several options?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a project I am working on which runs a process if a value is identified in a file

```
if (read_txt.Contains("one") == true)
   (do.something)
else if ((read_txt.Contains("two") == true)
   (do.something.else)
else
   (do.last.thing)
```

The (do.something) and (do.something.else) contains lots of things, like processes, if statements etc.

for example, (do.something) contains;

```
if (read_txt.Contains("one") == true)
   write_log
   process
   read_file
   if file.contains
        write_log
   else
        write_log
        process
   process
   if file.contains
        write_log
   else
        write_log
```

The issue I have is that if the file in 'read_txt' contains both "one" and "two", i want to be able to run both elements, (do.something) and (do.something.else), without copying the code out again as there is quite a bit.

What would be the best way to do this?

I am a beginner with C# but this project is helping me learn quite quickly!!

Comment: I would create a Function and or a `Bit wise` Enumerator

Comment: Well what is `do something else`? Is it calling a method or is the code just placed there? If it isn't calling a method, **make one.** Also, you don't need to explicitly check against `== true`. Can just be `file.Contains("one")`.

Comment: The (do.something.else) has roughly the same structure as (do.something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue I have is that if the file in 'read_txt' contains both "one" and "two", i want to be able to run both elements, (do.something) and (do.something.else), without copying the code out again as there is quite a bit.

That's easy, just don't make it an `else if`, just have two `if` statements.

```
bool foundNone = true;

if(read_txt.Contains("one"))
{
    DoFirstThing();
    foundNone = false;
}

if(read_txt.Contains("two"))
{
    DoSecondThing();
    foundNone = false;
}

if(foundNone)
{
   DoThirdThing();
}
```

This means it will run the code for each value found and won't stop when it finds one, but it still only does the last thing if *none* of the other options were hit.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool not12 = true;
if (read_txt.Contains("one")) { (do.something); not12 = false;}
if (read_txt.Contains("two")) {(do.something.else); not12 = false;}   
if(not12) (do.last.thing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function out of (do.something) and/or have your first if statement check for both being true at the same time such as:

```
if(read_txt.Contains("one") && read_txt.Contains("two"))
```